# Xamarin.Forms CarousalPage to Display All Children's Titles

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm a Xamarin noob. What I want to achieve is a carousal page that displays all the page titles. Similar to the Windows edition of WhatsApp (first image).

Currently, only my current page title is displayed (because it's a label on the page)(second image)

Thanks in Advance

[what I am after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN7RB.png)

[what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtRZJ.png)

Comment: Can't add images yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing are Tabs. Xamarin.Forms comes with built in support for tabbed **pages**. The Windows implementation looks just like your first picture, of course. The android application uses android style tab buttons at the top, and iOS uses iOS style tabs on the bottom of the screen.
Check out the documentation on tabbed pages on the Xamarin.Forms support website [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/tabbed-page/)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/carousel-page/) control and [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/) custom control.

Answer (score -1):

what you need is a polished navigation bar so try using in xaml;

```
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="SomeTitle" />
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

this will add new toolbar item to the navigation bar.